# Black screen on Galaxy A50 when trying to preview camera in the highest resolution using getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, camera, resolution, getusermedia, smartphone

I'm building a project where enduser can translate a text dynamically in several language using his back camera.

When i open the rear camera in the maximum resolution in 16/9, my personal phone (Samsung Galaxy Note 20) opens it in 4032x2268 and preview is displayed under the video tag, i can extract image to send it for analyse to my server. When i use my wife's phone (samsung A50), the taken resolution is 4128x2322 but nothing appears on the preview... (totally black preview).

However, when i try to grab an image from that stream it works !! Can anyone explain me how is that possible or how can i detect that the preview from video tag is totally black ?

Here is my HTML/JS code that causes this issue (all tests were done on chrome).

JS :

```
const video = document.querySelector('#video');

let constraints = { video: {
  frameRate: 15,
  height: { min: 480, ideal: 10000, max: 10000},
  aspectRatio: 1.7777777778
}}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream) => {
  video.srcObject = stream;
})
  .catch((err) => {
  alert(err);
});
```

HTML part :

```
<video style="width: 45%" id="video" autoplay playsinline></video>
```

Comment: _"Here is my demo page to debug this issue"_ - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve] _in the question itself_

Comment: It's possible you're asking too much of the <video> tag on the A50. If you use `height: { ideal: 2160}` in your constraints do you get useful results? Do you get anything on the browser's console log in the device when you get the black screen. (Viewing an android browser console log requires some setup work on your laptop.)

Comment: I tried so many things even your 'ideal' flag but i don't have any logs under console logs from my A50 chrome browser (remote device debug). It's like only the preview is broken without any error/warning but the content of it is fine... I currently blocked the resolution of the user to fullHD